# draw geoJson on map mapbox

Tags: android, sdk, mapbox, geojson

Is there another way for add geoJSON polygon to map using mapbox sdk 9.0 stable on android?

I have the following but not sure if it's correct:

```
GeoJsonSource source = new GeoJsonSource("geojson", geoJsonString); 
mapboxMap.addSource(source); 
mapboxMap.addLayer(new LineLayer("geojson", "geojson"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/click-on-a-single-layer/) from the Mapbox documentation shows how to add a GeoJSON polygon to your map with the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android. The relevant code is in the `onMapReady` callback, extracted below (I omitted the code related to adding a click listener, since that is not relevant for your question);

```
@Override
public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

  // Add the GeoJSON as a source to the map.
  addGeoJsonSourceToMap(style);

  // Create FillLayer with GeoJSON source and add the FillLayer to the map.
  if (style != null) {
    style.addLayer(new FillLayer(geoJsonLayerId, geoJsonSourceId)
         .withProperties(fillOpacity(0.5f)));
  }
}
```

The `addGeoJsonSourceToMap` helper method in this example loads the GeoJSON from an external URI, but in your case the first two lines of your provided code snippet would replace the `addGeoJsonSourceToMap(style);` call.

A `FillLayer` is used rather than a `LineLayer` since, per the [linked API reference documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/9.0.0/index.html):

`FillLayer`:

> A filled polygon with an optional stroked border.

`LineLayer`:

> A stroked line.

Answer (score -1):

**1.** Try adding the Source:

```js
// WARDS – 2020 – SOURCE
// url = 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/845bbfdb73944694b3b81c5636be46b5_0.geojson';
map.addSource(
  'ward-source', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: 'Wards.geojson'
  }
);
```

**2.** and the Layers:

```
// WARDS FILL
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'wards-fill',
  'type': 'fill',
  'source': 'wards-source',
  'layout': {},
  'paint': {
    'fill-color': '#627BC1',
    'fill-opacity': [
      'case',
      ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
      1,
      0.5
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Without looking at the source, you're not very likely to get upvotes for code in images. Please consider pasting actual code in text formatted as code.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.